# VB.NET String Data Manipulation for DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I want to manipulate my String data for example I have a x="20140118"
to y="01/18/2014" how can I do it? I need it for the value in DateTimePicker on VB.NET.
Thanks

Comment: If you think that `DateTimePicker.Value` needs `"01/18/2014"`(a `String`), i assume that you've set `OPTION STRICT` to `Off`. I strongly recomment to set it to `On` which will cause many compiler errors. That's a good thing because you'll learn a lot about .NET types and it'll prevent you also  from nasty conversion issues or runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTimePicker.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) wants a `DateTime` not a string. So you need to parse it:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("20140118", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
dateTimePicker1.Value = dt
```

- [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, just for the sake of completeness, if you need a string `01/18/2014` from the `DateTime` you can use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
Dim date As String = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If that is your local date format you could also use these more concise approaches:

1. )

   ```
    Dim date As String = dt.ToShortDateString()
   ```
2. )

   ```
   Dim date As String = dt.ToString("d")
   ```

Comment: Thanks Dude it works fine :) how can i mark this as answered ? I'm new here :D